# How to add canonical links on ALL URL's?

Tags: uri, 7

What is the best way to get canonical links on ALL URL's in D7?

I see nodes already have relative canonicals but I have a site with a lot of non node URL's that also need canonicals.

I added code to my `html.tpl.php` to add a canonical on any page but now I get double ups on node based pages.

Thanks for anyone taking a look at this.

**UPDATE:**
I used a `theme_html_head_alter()` hook to remove the node canonicals.
Then I added new canonicals into the `html.tpl.php` so every page has them and there is only one on the node pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a theme_html_head_alter() hook to remove the node canonicals.
Then I added new canonicals into the html.tpl.php so every page has them and there is only one on the node pages.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned elsewhere, global redirect is a good option. But even Metatag is a good module. It not only handles the canonical urls but also meta keywords, description, Copyright data and many more important Meta data including OG. So, you can also have a check on this module. http://drupal.org/project/metatag and a tutorial on how to get the canonical url to work on this link: http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/canonical-links-and-drupal-7

The one thing with meta tag module is that by default it will print relative canonical urls whereas I have seen major sites like smashingmagazine, engadget etc uses absolute. So, if you want that to happen then the second url is the key.

Comment: This is not really the problem, I want to add canonical link tags to ALL pages, not redirect a bunch of pages.

AFAIK it's fine to use relative canonicals.

Comment: Yes, Meta tags module will add the canonical links to the page headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... a simple module which:
>
> 1. Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if it is not being used.
> 2. Checks the current URL for a trailing slash, removes it if present and repeats check 1 with the new request.
> 3. Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.
> 4. Checks if the Clean URLs feature is enabled and then checks the current URL is being accessed using the clean method rather than the 'unclean' method.
> 5. Checks access to the URL. If the user does not have access to the path, then no redirects are done. This helps avoid exposing private aliased node's.
> 6. Make sure the case of the URL being accessed is the same as the one set by the author/administrator. For example, if you set the alias "articles/cake-making" to node/123, then the user can access the alias with any combination of case.
> 7. Most of the above options are configurable in the settings page. In Drupal 5 you can access this after enabling the globalredirect_admin module. In Drupal 6, the settings page is bundled into the module.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), go to its settings and

1. Click "edit" next to the **Global** settings
2. Go the **Canonical URL** field (under the *Advanced* tab)
3. Fill out the following:
   `http://yourdomain.com[current-page:url:relative]`

This will come in handy when you use multiple domains for one website. It will avoid duplicate content flags.

Comment: You can add a token instead of your "http://yourdomain.com" `[site:url][current-page:url:relative]`